# In Vert.x, should REST endpoints return Future<T> or T?

Tags: java, rest, future, vert.x

I am having a hard time finding documentation on which is the correct return type.

For example, if I have a REST endpoint which lookups and returns a String should the endpoint have a return type of `Future<String>` or `String`? Further, what impact would this have on the event loop (i.e. would returning `String` over `Future<String>` cause more blocking)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why have it return anything at all? Assuming it's an endpoint for a RESTful web service, it should just write the response to the output buffer of the associated routing context.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example? For context I come form a Spring/Springboot background where having a return type is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at section (2) of the quick-start at [https://vertx.io/get-started](https://vertx.io/get-started/), you'll see chunk of code I've pasted below (I've added some numbered comments):

```
// Mount the handler for all incoming requests at every path and HTTP method
router
  .route()  // (1)
  .handler(context -> {  // (2)
    // Get the address of the request
    String address = context.request().connection().remoteAddress().toString();
    // Get the query parameter "name"
    MultiMap queryParams = context.queryParams();
    String name = queryParams.contains("name") ? queryParams.get("name") : "unknown";
    // Write a json response
    context.json(  // (3)
      new JsonObject()
        .put("name", name)
        .put("address", address)
        .put("message", "Hello " + name + " connected from " + address)
    );
  });
```

What this is doing is:

1. Registering a `Handler` (basically a callback) that will be invoked for every request that the router receives.
2. The handler will be called with a `RoutingContext`, which contains references to an `HttpServerRequest` object representing the current request, as well as an `HttpServerResponse` object representing the response. The latter allows you to control the response that is sent back to the client (ie headers, body, etc).
3. `context.json()` is a convenience method for writing a JSON formatted response payload - the body will be correctly formatted, the content-type header will be set, etc.

Fundamentally, what `.json()` is doing is:

```
  final JsonObject myJson = ...;
  
  final Buffer myJsonBuffer = Json.encodeToBuffer(myJson);

  context.response()
      .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
      .write(myJsonBuffer);
```

Those last three lines are how the response is actually sent back to the client.

For a more detailed explanation, check out the Vert.x Web documentation regarding responses [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_simple_responses).

Comment: Thanks for your help and through answer. I think I needed to shift my thinking from the Spring world to the more reactive Vert.x world. This reply has helped with that.

Answer (score 0):

> Out of the box Vert.x allows any primitive/simple type, String, or
> buffers  to be sent as messages. However, it’s a convention and common
> practice in Vert.x to send messages as JSON

I guess this is the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_types_of_messages) you are looking for. You can return Strings to the eventBus. Though Json is mostly used

```
new JsonObject().put("key", "stringValue");
```

It's better to return the String than the Future. The Future will need special Codec.